# Q2 income and TDS on TRACES form 16 includes only July salary?

Tags: income-tax, india, tax-deduction

My current employer has deducted TDS in July by error. I am below tax bar, so on my TRACES form-16 "amount paid" or "TDS" for Q1,Q3,Q4 TDS details are not mentioned. But it mentions only July's earnings and TDS deducted for it. 
Is it correct to have a form 16 which shows only July's salary in Q2 ?

Comment: I have edited the country tag as India. Please change if different.

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect to have a form 16 that does not show the full salary paid. Incase it is taking time to get this rectified, when you file the returns, mention the correct salary received and the tax deducted, if you use the Income Tax website for filing, it would also show the refund amount.

Edit:
If an individual is deemed tax payer, all the income in terms of salary etc should be reported and tax deducted also reported to TRACE. There could be cases where excess tax was deducted and hence there can only be salary paid and no tax deducted. In your case, it could have been a gap where originally you were not supposed to a tax payer but tax got deducted by error.

Comment: so Q1, Q3,Q4 salary also has to be showed on Traces form-16 even if TDS was not deducted in those quarters. ?

Comment: Yes. The tax was deducted in July by error. But my question is : Under Q2 "amount paid/credited" section of Form-16 (traces), should only July salary be mentioned or entire Q2's earning should be mentioned ?

Comment: For all Quarters complete salary paid should be mentioned.